# Return everything before nth character or final space before nth character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im using the following code, which trims everything up to the last word proceeding a space at the 50 character mark:

```
SELECT RTRIM(
    CASE
        -- when the length is less than 50, or the character at position 50 is part of the last word, return the entire string
        WHEN LEN(CompanyName) < 50 OR (SUBSTRING(CompanyName,50,1) <> ' ' AND CHARINDEX(' ',CompanyName,50) = 0)
            THEN CompanyName
        -- when the character at position 50 is a space, return the first 50 characters of the string
        WHEN SUBSTRING(CompanyName,50,1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(CompanyName, 50)
        -- when the character at position 50 is a word, cut off the string at the next space after 50
        WHEN SUBSTRING(CompanyName,50,1) <> ' '
            THEN LEFT(CompanyName,CHARINDEX(' ',CompanyName,50) - 1)
    END) AS first_50
FROM Organisation
```

Which i found on the following thread.

[Use SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX to get last complete word in field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909143/use-substring-and-charindex-to-get-last-complete-word-in-field)

Basically i need the last block to get everything before the final space rather than after, so the length of the results never exceeds 50 characters.

--- EDIT ---------

As an example:

> This is an e[x]ample string

If the 50th character falls on the x in example, the code above will give me:

> This is an example

What i need is for it to return:

> This is an

So everything up to the last occurrence of a space character before the 50th character.

Comment: If all you want to do is to cut the strings up to the first occurrence of a space character and in case there is no space before the 50th character everything up to the 50th character, that's simple, but I'm not sure what you are really looking for.

Comment: Please see my edit, sorry if it wasn't clear. Basically the field in the database will only fit 50 characters so i need to TRIM it but i don't want to have half a word at the end of the string.

Comment: You need to use `REVERSE()` function to get the position of the last space before 50th character. I updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first cut the string to its first 50 characters to make sure it will never go beyond that. Then Apply the `LEFT`, and `CHARINDEX()` with `REVERSE()` function and cut by the first occurrence of a space

```
 select LEFT(SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 1, 50), 
             50 - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(CompanyName, 1, 50)))) 
 from Organization;
```