# Retain string till character limit with last complete word, and store remaining words in 2nd variable

Tags: r, regex

Take these example strings, I want to split them such that the length is limited to X or less characters, a complete word is at the end of each string, and the remaining part is stored in another column. The words are always separated by space. I came across [this partial solution in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909143/use-substring-and-charindex-to-get-last-complete-word-in-field) (doesn't create variable for extra words). However I need to do it in R. I was provided the first half solution in a previous question, this doesn't have the remaining words in new variables. I need help to create the new variable

```
 {gsub(patt="(^.{2,100})([ ].+)", repl="\\1",y)}
```

For example:

```
XOVEW VJIEW NI **stays** XOVEW VJIEW NI (assuming X is 14)
XOVEW VJIEW NIGOI **becomes** XOVEW VJIEW (NIGOI goes to a new vector) 
XOVEW VJIEWNIGOI **becomes** XOVEW (assuming X is 14)
```

So new variable will contain `c("NIGOI","VJIEWNIGOI")` coming from 2nd and 3rd row above.

Comment: `v1 <-  ifelse( nchar(vect) > 14, gsub( "(.*)\\s+(\\w+)", "\\1 - \\2", vect),vect);`
`values <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', lapply(strsplit(v1,split="-"), \`length<-\`,2)));`, Let me know if this solves your problem, where vect is your input rows and values are final output

Comment: You got it. I've been working on this all day! thanks. Could you explain the do.call statement used here a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 <- ifelse( nchar(vect) > 14, gsub( "(.*)\\s+(\\w+)", "\\1 - \\2", vect),vect); 

values <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', lapply(strsplit(v1,split="-"), `length<-`,2)));
```

**Output**:

```
     [,1]             [,2]         
[1,] "XOVEW VJIEW NI" NA           
[2,] "XOVEW VJIEW "   " NIGOI"     
[3,] "XOVEW "         " VJIEWNIGOI"
```

I have created a small vector which will check if your string length is greater or smaller than 14 (`?nchar` in case you want to understand it).

Then wherever, it is longer than 14 I have created a string seperated by a dash, This is just to segregate the two strings, where the first strings deptics any collection of word which is not the last one, the second string matches the last word of the statement.

To match these I used regex, a `dot` represents any character, a `star` zero or more matches(together it means any character with zero or more matches) , a `\\s+` matches 1 or more spaces and `\\w+` matches one or more words. Collectively the match is such that it should have last word segregated with rest of the string in cases where string length is more than 14 within ifelse. Also these characters are further captured into `\\1` and `\\2` with a dash separation. where `\\1` matches the first non last word match and `\\2` match the last word of the string.

At last `do.call` is used with with `rbind`(bind all the rows) and `lapply`(to get even number of columns across all the elements)

I hope this explains your query.

Comment: Yes I have understood it, thanks for the detailed explanation. I knew I had nchar but was unable to come up with a logic that you have used to separate the string into two. In the do.call('rbind',lapply((strsplit(..)),`length<-`,2) what is `length<-`,2 for?

Comment: Its a function search ?\`length<-\`

Comment: Its another way of saying length(x) <-2